# useState is not rendering as expected

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-firebase

I have a state named `chats` in which i am storing all messages from firebase and i'm trying to render it in app. but it does not render
here is my component's state:

```
  const [chats, setChats] = useState([]);
```

I am bringing messages in UseEffect hook to get it on running of app

```
useEffect(() => {
    let merged_uid = uid_merger(current_user.id, chat_user.uid);
    database()
      .ref('/')
      .child(`chats/${merged_uid}`)
      .on('child_added', (msgs) => {
        console.log(msgs);
        chats.push(msgs.val());
        setChats(chats);
      });
  }, []);
```

but id does not render.

Comment: Instead of `chats.push(msgs.val());`, you should do `setChats(c => ({...c, msgs.val()}))`.

Answer (score 2):

since chats is a state you can't mutate it using `chats.push(msgs.val());` instead what you need to do is to replace

```
chats.push(msgs.val());
setChats(chats);
```

with

```
setChats([...chats, msgs.val()])
```

Comment: it only renders last node.why is that?

Comment: this is how i'm rendering 
`{chats.map((v, i) => { 
return (<View style={styles.msgView} key={i}>
                <Text>{v.message}</Text>
              </View>); })
}`

Comment: and if i do this `setChats([...chats, chats.push(msgs.val())]);` it all except last node.

Comment: @AqsaMaan I'm not seeing anything wrong with your map function. I am not that familiar with fetching from firebase but it seems to me that you are only retrieving the data once in your useEffect. Maybe you need to have some sort of for loop there?

Comment: no i dont need loop. I only need to render on component mount. but i'm getting nothing in last node

Comment: In that case I recommend that you debug by console log both the chats state and message and see what you get in return.

Comment: I have checked it. in chats, i am getting all messages but it does not render last one. I mean it does render last one but messenge shoes empty.

Comment: like this:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L1XbUpQu5JAWQ0ImOSadof8i9D0-qjeu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AqsaMaan Thank you for sending an example of the screenshot to clarify. Can you send another screen shot with higher values? like 10 messages?

Comment: I'm wonder if this is because it is being rendered on some sort of emulator. If this is on a browser then it should've rendered all messages for sure.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eozDc0Ltff7wghtc-v7FfA7HtW16dWZH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks Aqsa. I'm pretty sure that this is not a react issue. It could be something that has to do with your styling. Can you please paste what you use for styling the component? for example I'm noticing that the first and last element are styled differently

Comment: its not first and last. its more like sender and receiver but last message always show like yellow which is of sender even if last msg is not of sender

Comment: here is code :https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qj2Ta0lVzAitIrXP78Qa5jowG01lRPBT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AqsaMaan please replace setChats([...chats, chats.push(msgs.val())]) with setChats([...chats, msgs.val()])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230479/discussion-between-aqsa-maan-and-laserany).